# When using strings with numbers at the start in an array key (Indesign 2017, extendscript) they don't get added to the array

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Observe:

```
    var groupedLinks = new Array;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      linkName = "59notgonnawork" + i;
      groupedLinks[linkName] = new Array;
    }
```

I would have expected the result to be the array groupedLinks to be filled up with 5 new keys, the value would be 5 empty arrays.

The actual result in extendscript would be ... grouplinks ... empty.

If I would change this example to be:

```
    var groupedLinks = new Array;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      linkName = "notgonnawork" + i;

      groupedLinks[linkName] = new Array;
    }
```

It would work perfectly. The only change is the missing "59" at the start of the string used for the array key.

**Note that this works perfectly when I run it in console for chrome or firefox. It seems to be indesign and/or extendscript fooling around.**

Anything have any ideas why ? I've meanwhile worked around the problem but I'm intrigued.

Answer (score 4):

> I would have expected the result to be the array groupedLinks to be filled up with 5 new keys, the value would be 5 empty arrays.

That's exactly what it does, but the way you're viewing the data is likely concealing it because you're not using the proper data structure. Also, property access won't work without using `[]` because identifiers may not start with a number, so you'd need:

```
groupedLinks["59notgonnawork0"]
```

What you're doing isn't meant for arrays, which are expecting sequential numeric indices (though they can technically be assigned other properties too). The type of structure you should be using is a plain object instead.

```
var groupedLinks = {};
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const linkName = "59notgonnawork" + i;
  groupedLinks[linkName] = new Array; // Array? plain Object? Depends on its use.
}
```

Comment: does this work for you though ? For me the object has the exact same issue as the array. 

As to the array or plain object question -> I want multiple objects to be there, so array with objects would be my go to option.

Comment: @ElDorado: The only issue I can see is that the property identifier starts with a number, and so as I noted in my answer, you need to use brackets to access the property. In other words you can *not* do this: `groupedLinks.59notgonnawork0` but you *can* do this: `groupedLinks["59notgonnawork0"]`

Comment: Yeah I got that, I'm checking in the debugger extendscript provides. [] or {}, both times when I use numbers in the "key" it fails.

    var groupedLinks = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      linkName = "69notgonnawork" + i;

      groupedLinks[linkName] = new Array;
    }

Comment: The `[]` and `{}` (array vs object) doesn't make a difference. I'm just noting that an array is for numeric indices, and the proper structure would be an object. I don't know what you mean when you say it "fails". With no description of *how* it fails, I can only point out potential problems visible in the code. Since the only difference is the leading number, I can only guess that you're trying to do `groupedLinks.59notgonnawork0` somewhere, which is invalid.

Comment: It fails in the sense that it will not add those indices to the array. 

I understand what you're saying with arrays and objects and the numeric indices for arrays. 

The issue is that extendscript doesn't seem to care about the difference.

I can't seem to use my filenames as indices because if they have numeric values as first characters they just get ignored when you add them to the array.

Comment: @ElDorado Why do you think they're ignored? How are you using them that they seem to not be present? This is why we usually like to have a full yet minimal demonstration of the issue in a question.

Comment: Well I'd love to demo it to you ... Unfortunately there isn't a codepen thingie for extendscript and any modern browser doesn't have the issue.

I think they're ignored because when I run the piece of code in my examples and I use the extendscript toolkit and inspect the object/array, they're not there. 

It should be easy to simulate if you have indesign at your disposal. I'd love to make it easier I just don't know how.

Comment: @ElDorado: OK, I'll delete this answer, since it isn't really solving anything. Best of luck!

Comment: Flagged it either way. It appears I failed at asking a clear question ;-). I think it has to do with extendscript or the extendscript debugger more than anything really "JavaScript" related. Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to push the value in the array on each iteration.

```
 var groupedLinks = new Array;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  linkName = "59notgonnawork" + i;

  groupedLinks.push(linkName);
}
```

Comment: Because the OP is not looking to store just a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

ExtendScript Arrays are great for stocking data per indeces. If you need key/values objects, why not use… Objects ?

```js
var groupedLinks = {};
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  linkName = "59notgonnawork" + i;

  groupedLinks[linkName] = "Whatever…";
}

alert( groupedLinks["59notgonnawork0" ] ); //"Whatever…"
```